# Segmentation fault in dynamic string array

Tags: arrays, c, string, dynamic

I have an array of strings that is dynamically sized (I won't know the size of the strings at compile) that keeps giving me a segmentation fault error. The array is contained in a struct called `hm` and it has an array for the strings as well as an array for values. This part of the code is only to resize the string array properly when a new string is added to the struct.
I am relatively new to C and structs, so if there is a better way to implement this I would love to hear about it. I have already tried looking around for this situation and most seem to be having the issue with the outer array using `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char*)`, but when I changed that the issue still happens.

```
//problematic part of the function
char** t = (char**)realloc(hm->keys, hm->size * sizeof(char*));
if (t) hm->keys = t;
for (i = 0; i < hm->size; i++) {
    char* temp = (char*)realloc(hm->keys[i], hm->largestKey * sizeof(char)); //seg fault here
    if (temp) {
        hm->keys[i] = temp;
    }
}

//struct
typedef struct HM_struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t largestKey;
    char** keys;
    int* values;

    void (*add)(struct HM_struct* hm, char* key, int value);
} HM;
```

Comment: Your code does call either `malloc()` or `calloc()` before calling `realloc()`, right?

Comment: You can't use `realloc()` there because not all of the `hm->keys[i]` have been initialized.

Comment: [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You can use `realloc()` for the elements that were in the `keys` array before you reallocated it, but you have to use `malloc()` for the new elements that were added.

Comment: Which means you need to save the old size before you grow the array.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, you were right, I forgot to do ```malloc()``` for the newly added string. As for casting, that's something my professor told me to do, so I will probably keep doing that as long as I am in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you `realloc()` and increase the allocated memory size, the new memory is not initialised (or with a debug library, initialised to a sentinal value). So, assuming you know the `oldSize`, a quick fix is:

```
char** t = realloc(hm->keys, hm->size * sizeof(char*)); // As before
if (t) hm->keys = t; // As before
for (i = oldSize; i < hm->size; i++)
    hm->keys[i] = NULL;
```

Now, according to the [`realloc()` definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), when you call:

```
char* temp = realloc(NULL, hm->largestKey * sizeof(char));
```

It behaves as:

```
char* temp = malloc(hm->largestKey * sizeof(char));
```